# Extract an element from an XML file by position in the hierarchy rather than by name

Tags: xml, powershell, xmldom

I have an XML file like this :

```
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I have Powershell script like this :

```
$xmlData = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xmlData.Load('c:\test\data.xml')
$xmlData.note.body # I want to remove "note.body" to change to use function
```

Can I get the value of what is currently element `note.body` without having to use the element *names*, i.e., can I extract values by the target element's *position in the document hierarchy*?

The idea is to have a script that continues to work even after element names in the input XML change (but not the document's *structure*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to locate the element of interest *positionally*, use the generic XML DOM properties:

In **PowerShell *Core***:

```sh
# Extract the text from the *last child* of the *document element*.
# This is the positional equivalent of your $xmlData.note.body call.
# Of course, you can use specific indices such as [2] as well.
$xmlData.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[-1].InnerText
```

With your sample document, the output is `Don't forget me this weekend!`, as expected.

---

In ***Windows PowerShell*** (all workarounds work in PowerShell Core too):

**A *bug* prevents the use of `[-1]`** to refer to the *last* element of the collection in this case.

**Workaround 1**:

```sh
$childNodes = $xmlData.DocumentElement.ChildNodes  
$childNodes[$childNodes.Count-1].InnerText
```

**Workaround 2**:

You've proposed the following alternative, which is much simpler, albeit less efficient (which probably won't matter):

Use [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) to extract the `.InnerText` values from *all* child nodes up front - which returns a regular PowerShell array - and apply `[-1]` to *that*:

```sh
$xmlData.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.InnerText[-1]
```

**Workaround 3**, proposed by [Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak):

```sh
$xmlData.DocumentElement.ChildNodes |
  Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty InnerText
```

`Select-Object -Last 1` does succeed in extracting the last child element, and `-ExpandProperty InnerText` then returns the `.InnerText` property value.

Note that this solution will typically perform worst among the workarounds, due to use of a cmdlet in the pipeline, though, again, this likely won't matter in practice, unless you call this code in a loop with a high iteration count.